# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when testing for contains function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, hashtable

Hi I'm new to Python and I'm implementing a hash table in Python and I'm doing a unit test for my contains method.This is my contains method

```
 def __contains__(self,key):
    position=self.hash_value(key)
    for _ in range(self.table_size):
        if self.array[position][0]==key:
            return True
        elif self.array[position] is None:
            return False
        position=(position+1)%self.table_size
    return False
```

So I did my unit test like this:

```
 def testContains(self):
    my_table=HashTableLinear(3)
    my_table["Julian"] = "FIT1008"
    my_table["Phillip"] = "FIT1045"
    self.assertEqual("a" in my_table,False)
    self.assertEqual("Julian" in my_table,True)
```

But i got an error:

```
 if self.array[position][0]==key:
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my contains method?How do I fix it?Any help will be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem will be the `None` value of `self.array[position]`, So the thing you can do is change the order of the conditions like this :

```
for _ in range(self.table_size):
    if self.array[position] is None:
        return False
    elif self.array[position][0]==key:
        return True
    position=(position+1)%self.table_size
```

Here it will first check for the value of array, If it is not none it will  go to second condition. The problem in your code is when it checks the first condition there should be some value for array, It should not be none, If it is none It will throw the error that you got.